# PHP Hover should add css but only to that element

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have this PHP which lists cards.

**What I want:** When a user hovers over the entire element, make the title bolder, arrow go left and zoom in the image **on that hovered element**.

```
<div class="posti-class row">
    <?php
    $timeline_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=> 'blablabla', 'showposts' => 4, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'has_password' => false, 'portfolio_category' => 'case-studies') );
    $i = 0;
    while( $timeline_posts->have_posts() ): $timeline_posts->the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hoverpostzoom">
            <div class="portfolio-new-image-n">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>

                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10" style="padding:0;">
                        <h4  class="title-ofpostc" style="color: #6796BF"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="padding:0;">
                        <div class="arrow-ofpostc" style="font-size: 25px; color: #6796BF; font-weight: 600; text-align: right;"> &#x2192; </div>
                    </div>



                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        jQuery('.hoverpostzoom').hover(function () {
            jQuery('.title-ofpostc').addClass('titlehovereff');
            jQuery('.arrow-ofpostc').addClass('arrowhovereff');
        }, function () {
            jQuery('.title-ofpostc').removeClass('titlehovereff');
            jQuery('.arrow-ofpostc').removeClass('arrowhovereff');
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .titlehovereff {
        color: #6796BF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .arrowhovereff{
        padding-right: 10px;
        transition: 0.5s all;
    }

</style>
```

This is a good except it makes ALL the arrows go left, not just on the currect hovered one. 
What am I missing here ?

Note: I have to write it all in `<script>` and `<style>` tags in the same document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will target *every* matching element:

```
jQuery('.title-ofpostc')
```

Which, as you've found, is all of them.  There are a couple ways to target the specific element in question.  Since you're in the context of an event handler and the target elements are within the element which raised the event, you can make use of `this` as the context in which to match elements.  Something like:

```
jQuery('.title-ofpostc', jQuery(this)).addClass('tilehovereff');
```

Or possibly even without wrapping `this` in a jQuery object, I'm not sure:

```
jQuery('.title-ofpostc', this).addClass('tilehovereff');
```

When using the `jQuery()` function to match elements, an optional second argument is a context or containing element in which to find the matches.

Alternatively, you could also use DOM traversal methods to reach the target.  Such as starting on the current element which raised the event and using `.find()` therein.  Something like:

```
jQuery(this).find('.title-ofpostc').addClass('tilehovereff');
```

This approach can be useful when you need to traverse up and down the DOM, such as to find an element within a sibling of a parent element or something of that nature, chaining calls to things like `.closest()` and `.find()` and other such jQuery functions.

Comment: This works great for the arrow! But the font wont go bold for some reason. Still, correct aswer. Thank you @David!